# Are there any 2D alternatives to Unity?

Tags: software-recommendation, launcher, unity-2d, alternative, 2d

I'm just wondering if there are any **2D** alternatives to Unity (excluding KDE, XFCE, LXDE, etc.) that have a modern look to them.  I like Unity (since I'm newer to Ubuntu) but I just think an alternative would be cool.  Replies would be appreciated.

PS: My computer is a few years old and **only has 2d acceleration.**

Answer (score 2):

Gnome 3 has a very modern look and scales nicely on older hardware:

[image]

You can install Gnome 3 by [clicking here [image: Install gnome-shell]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-shell) or by entering the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

Once Gnome 3 is installed, simply log out, click the gear icon next to your name on the login screen and select "Gnome".

Comment: I said 2D though.

Comment: @Schism430: I would suggest trying Gnome 3 anyway - it runs almost flawlessly on a netbook with integrated graphics.

Comment: Gnome 3 needs 3d acceleration, which I don't have.  I'll try the fallback mode, though.

Comment: Update: The normal GNOME 3 doesn't work, but the fallback does

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I installed Pantheon, and except for the exclusion of a background, it is ok for me.   Case closed.

Comment: Update:  Exclusion of a background EVERYWHERE.  That's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 11.10, you should have a Unity 2D option, which will be the default if your hardware is detected as being incapable of running 3D.

Comment: That's my current desktop environment, actually

Answer (score 0):

There are two implementations of Unity. The default one is based on Compiz and hence requires accelerated graphics. The other is a "plain" Qt app, which does not require any acceleration. It's quite nice, almost identical to the accelerated Unity. It's installed by default in 11.10. You just choose it before you log in. It's the button next to the password field. If you're in 11.04, then you can install it by [clicking this link](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/unity-2d)